# Add the count of two select queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregate-functions, union

I have an employee table, I need to fetch the total count of employees based on course 1 and course 2 for the last 12 months from the specified month.

Table Design

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Field     | Type        |   
+-----------+-------------+    | 
| emp_name  | varchar(30) | 
| join_date | date        | 
| emp_id    | int(5)      | 
| c1_sub    | date        | 
| c1_expire | date        | 
| c2_sub    | date        | 
| c2_expire | date        | 
| activity  | varchar(30) | 
| group     | varchar(30) | 
+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to show the output below. c1_sub activation date and c2_sub activation date based on this I want to show the last 12 months' employee count.

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| Month     | single      |Dual       |   
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| Dec 22    | 10          | 2         |
| Nov 22    | 8           | 4         |
| Oct 22    | 3           | 5         |
| ......    | .           | 
| ......    | .           | 
| ......    | .           | 
| Dec 21    | 5           | 4
| Nov 21    | 6           | 5
| Oct 21    | 7           | 6
| Sept 21   | 7           | 8
+-----------+-------------+------------|
```

I tried with the following queries, but I am getting without add of course 1 and course 2 student count. I am not aware of where to use the sum function.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM,[c1_sub]) AS Month
      , YEAR([c1_sub]) AS Year,
        sum(case when [activity] = 'Single' then 1 else 0 end) AS Single,
        sum(case when [activity] = 'Dual' then 1 else 0 end) AS Dual
    FROM [Employee]
    WHERE [Group Name] !='Test' AND
    [c1_sub] IS Not NULL AND [c2_sub] IS NULL AND 
    [c1_sub] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
    GROUP BY YEAR([c1_sub]), DATENAME(MM,[c1_sub]) )

    UNION  ALL

        SELECT DATENAME(MM,[c2_sub]) AS Month
      , YEAR([c2_sub]) AS Year,
        sum(case when [activity] = 'Single' then 1 else 0 end) AS Single,
        sum(case when [activity] = 'Dual' then 1 else 0 end) AS Dual
    FROM [Employee]
    WHERE [Group Name] !='Test' AND
    [c2_sub] IS NOT NULL AND 
    [c2_sub] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
    GROUP BY YEAR([c2_sub]), DATENAME(MM,[c2_sub]);
```

When I use union all, I am getting a different result than what I was expected,

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| Month     | single      |Dual       |   
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| Dec 22    | 10          | 2         |
| Dec 22    | 2           | 3         |
| Nov 22    | 8           | 4         |
| Nov 22    | 2           | 5         |

| Oct 22    | 3           | 5         |
| ......    | .           | 
| ......    | .           | 
| ......    | .           | 
| Dec 21    | 5           | 4
| Nov 21    | 6           | 5
| Oct 21    | 7           | 6
| Sept 21   | 7           | 8
+-----------+-------------+------------|
```

But, I am getting course 1 activation and count 2 activation separately instead of adding of these two value.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two data sets *before* you aggregate the data, rather than *after*.

```
SELECT
  DATENAME(MM,[sub_date]) AS Month,
  YEAR([sub_date]) AS Year,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [activity] = 'Single' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Single,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [activity] = 'Dual'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dual
FROM
(
  SELECT
    c1_sub   AS sub_date,
    [activity]
  FROM
    [Employee]
  WHERE
        [Group Name] !='Test'
    AND [c1_sub] IS NOT NULL
    AND [c2_sub] IS NULL
    AND [c1_sub] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    c2_sub,
    [activity]
  FROM
    [Employee]
  WHERE
        [Group Name] !='Test'
    AND [c2_sub] IS NOT NULL
    AND [c2_sub] BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()   
)
  AS combined
GROUP BY
  DATENAME(MM,[sub_date])
  YEAR([sub_date])
```

Also, the year and month part is "unusual", because it converts the data to a non-date type *and* splits it over two columns.

The normal way to group by month is to round down to the start of the month, retaining the date datatype and keeping it in a single column...

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [sub_date]), 0)
```

Comment: DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [sub_date]), 0) -- i donot understand this, please explain it

Comment: @KalaiSelvi Calculate the number of *whole* months that have passed since date zero. Add that number of months to date zero. The result is the input date rounded down to the start of the month.